# What is an intuitive proof that Mutual Information is non-negative?

Tags: information-theory

I would like to know why mutual information is always non-negative. I learnt that mutual information I(X;Y) =  H(Y) - H(Y|X). However, it seems to me that H(Y) is just a distribution, while Y|X is another distribution, since it is a slice of the joint distribution at a particular x. And hence the probability of Y|X could have more entropy than the marginal probability distribution of X. And thus I(X;Y) could be negative.

However it is stated otherwise. What is an intuitive explanation? I have seen proofs that use KL divergence and jensen's inequality, but it is not intuitive to me.

Comment: Some corrections - firstly $H(Y)$ is not a distribution at all, it's the entropy of the law of $Y$. I'm guessing you just misspoke here. Secondly, $H(Y|X)$ is not the entropy of a 'slice' of the joint law, but the average of the entropies of all slices, i.e., $H(Y|X) = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim P_X}[H(Y|X = x)].$ So, while you're correct in that for some choice of $x$, $H(Y|X = x)$ can be bigger than $H(Y),$ the claim is that the average $H(Y|X) \le H(Y)$.

Comment: Anyway, I'll raise two issues. First, could you explain what would be more intuitive for you? What style of proof would convince you more easily? The tension here really is the demand of intuitiveness and of rigour, which can be subtle. I can think of *operational* proofs via the source coding theorem, but this is probably going beyond your exposure to information theory so far. Roughly this says that given access to side information $X$ the optimal compression of a $Y$-source is at rate $H(Y|X).$ But you could have ignored $X$ in your compression, to get rate $H(Y)$. This is suboptimal,

Comment: (contd.) so $H(Y) \ge H(Y|X)$. I don't think this is more intuitive per se, but it's more operational. Secondly, and more importantly, I think that you're asking the wrong question. You should be trying to build up intuition about Jensen's inequality, not build up intuition about conditional entropy without relying on the tools that convexity gives us. Jensen's inequality in particular, and convexity in general, are powerful and ubiquitous tools, and while chasing a particular proof without these can be fun, I think internalising these concepts will be very useful across your career.

Comment: Thanks, I think understanding that H(Y|X) is not entropy of a slice of the distribution cleared up the confusion for me.